# Sum of random variables is continuous

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

Let $X$, $Y$ be independent random variables. Assuming that $X$ is continuous ($\forall_{x\in\mathbb{R}}P(X=x)=0)$. Show that $X+Y$ is continuous.

My approach:

Let $x\in\mathbb{R}$.
\begin{align}
P(X+Y=x)&=P(\bigcup_{y\in\mathbb{R}}\{X=y \land Y=x-y\})\\
&\leq\sum\limits_{y\in\mathbb{R}}P(X=y\land Y=x-y)\\
&=\sum\limits_{y\in\mathbb{R}}P(X=y)P(Y=x-y)
\end{align}

And since $(\forall_{x\in\mathbb{R}}P(X=x)=0)$ we get:

$$\sum\limits_{y\in\mathbb{R}}P(X=y)P(Y=x-y)=\sum\limits_{y\in\mathbb{R}}0\cdot P(Y=x-y)=0$$

Is this proof correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument works only when $X$ is discrete. Measures do not behave well with uncountable unions. The correct argument uses Fubini;s Theorem: $P\{X+Y=z\}=\int P\{X=z-y\}dF_Y(y)=0$ because $P\{X=z-y\}=0$ for all $y$.

Comment: Thank you so much!